# No Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) on Office 365 Group

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, cewp

thanks in advance for your time with the below query.

I have a SharePoint Online site and an Office 365 Group.

On the SharePoint Online site I have the CEWP (Content Editor Web Part) which I can add to a page successfully.

However, on the Office 365 Group I can not see it in the web-parts when editing a page.

I've tried enabling feature such as publishing, standard site features, enterprise site features, etc.  Custom scripts are already enabled/allowed in the admin settings.  I've tried creating sub-sites.  But still can't see it appear in the list of web-parts.  I've even tried exporting a CEWP from a SharePoint Online site and importing into my Office 365 group, but I recieve the error 'A web part or web form control on this page cannot be displayed or imported.  You don't have add and customize pages permissions required to perform this action'.  I am an owner of the group.

Is this missing CEWP a known limitation of Office 365 groups?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a while back so went through a support call with MS to resolve it.

Turns out that an O365 Group or an O365 Team that was created some time after the Group was created has custom scripting is denied by default,even if it's turned on at the SP Admin settings page

You need to enable it using the following powershell command using the SharePoint online management shell.

Set-SPOsite  -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
Where  is the URL of the site you are enabling scripting.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I used the below script

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://[yourtenant]-admin.sharepoint.com
```

Once you run this, it'll ask for credentials, login with the Admin account

Now run the below command

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://[yourtenant].sharepoint.com/[siteurl] -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

Please avoid trailing slashes in the end of the URL, otherwise it'll throw an error

i.e don't have slash in the end like this `https://mysite.Sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/`

Also, I enabled the `SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure` in the Site Collection Features and `SharePoint Server Publishing` in the Site Features

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable custom script on office 365.To enable Custom Script feature via SharePoint admin center >
       Settings > Custom Script, It takes about **24 hours** for the change to
       take effect.

Please find the below steps.

- Go to Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Site
  Collection Features > SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure > Active.
- Go to Site Settings > Site Actions > Manage site features > SharePoint Server Publishing > Activate.

Also check weather your top level site collection is created using **Team Site template**.If it is Developer Template ,CEWP[Content Editor Web Part] will not be available.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Custom scripts are already enabled and so is Publishing as advised in my question.  This is an Office 365 group, and I've created a new team-site within it based on the team-site template.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Could you please confirm the CEWP is working now?

Comment: No it is not, your answer advises of steps that I have already taken before I raised this question.